# data store how to get current data loaded in the page

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, javascript-framework

i need some data in Ext.data.Store where data are loaded to the page by the controller

```
var model1 = this.store.getAt(a.index);
    App.views.start.load(model1);   
    App.views.viewport.reveal('start');
```

inside the page start.js

```
var s=new Ext.data.Store({
            model: App.models.quiz, 
            data ://some data presently loaded in the page            
            autoLoad:true      
        });
```

Is there any method to get the current data in the page  in the the data store

Comment: Did u tried the getRecord() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you get the data into display in the first place?

I'd just keep a reference to the origin of the data and pass them on to the new store.